# Why doesn't gnuplot 4.6 plot window have featues of Gnuplot 4.4?

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

Few days back I switched from Gnuplot 4.4 to 4.6 only to make use of do loop feature. However, now I find that this version is quite bad when it comes to GUI. I tried both patchlevels 3 and 6 and found both to be quite bad at GUI. First, when I try to interactively plot something from the terminal, 'Tab' simply doesn't work: instead of completing the filename, it simply adds some old filename in front of whatever letters I type. Second, there are no back/forward arrows for zooming the plot in either directions. Then I don't see any grid option and refresh option and so on. Is there any problem with the way I installed it? Or are all these coming in updates?

I am using Ubuntu. When I start gnuplot, it shows me x11 terminal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should mention which operating system and which gnuplot terminal you are using. For me, everything is working fine on pl6, Linux, q11 terminal.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. When I start gnuplot, it shows me x11 terminal. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gnuplot 4.6 that comes with the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories looks OK with the default terminal, which is `wxt`:

[image]

Now, I'm suspecting that you met the same problem as me before I upgraded Ubuntu and you installed gnuplot 4.6 from source on Ubuntu 12.04, whose repositories come with gnuplot 4.4. When you install from source you might experience the lack of some terminals, in particular `wxt`. I do not know the details behind this issue, but I'm guessing some libraries needed for those terminals are somehow not available in Ubuntu 12.04.

For what it's worth, at least the `epslatex` terminal, which is the one I normally use on a non upgraded machine, seems to work flawlessly even when installing gnuplot 4.6 from source on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Sorry for so late reply, I will try to upgrade to latest ubuntu and then would try gnuplot 4.6. Thanks